# How can I change the color of my tab Bar in Corona SDK

Tags: colors, sdk, coronasdk, opacity, tabbar

I use Corona SDK and I have a question.
Is it possible to change the color and the apcity of a tab Bar and if yes can you show me how can I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: I think its not possible, if you want can use the custom tabBar using the images.

Answer (score 0):

The widget.newTabBar() is customizable.  See the docs here:

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newTabBar.html